# Fastest way to handle threading with callback in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm playing around with some measurement instruments through PyVisa (Python wrapper for VISA). Specifically I need to read the measurement value from four instruments, similar to this:

```
current1 = instrument1.ask("READ?")
current2 = instrument2.ask("READ?")
current3 = instrument3.ask("READ?")
current4 = instrument4.ask("READ?")
```

For my application, speed is a must. Individually, I can get between 50 and 200 measurements per second from the four instruments, but unfortunately my current code evaluates the four instruments serially.

From what I've read, there's some options with Threading and Multiprocessing in Python, but it's not obvious what the best, and fastest, option for me. 
Best case scenario I will be spawning ~4x50 threads per second, so overhead is a bit of a concern.

The task is in no way CPU intensive, it is simply a matter of waiting for the readout from the instrument.

Any advice on what the proper course of action might be?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not have 4 static threads, each looking at a single instrument continuously? That way you don't have to keep creating and joining threads.

Comment: You could try a threadpool. In that way you don't get any thread overheads..

Comment: @Loocid I'm not sure what you mean by static threads for python, but I need to read the four values at the same time, i.e. even for my best-case scenario I will always be limited by the slowest thread. But that is fine, as long as I don't have to read from the instruments in a serial manner! =)

Comment: @Bjarke I'm saying, rather than spawning new threads each time you want to try and read, instead have 4 threads that stay alive for your entire process.

Comment: Your description of the problem has not mentioned callback, do you need a callback or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module in python. Because of the way the python interpreter is written, the threading module for python actually slows down your application when using multiple threads on a computer with multiple processors. This is due to something called the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) which only allows one python thread per process to be run at a time. This makes things like memory management and concurrency easier for the interpreter.

I would suggest trying to create a process for each instrument (producer process) and send the results to a shared queue that gets processed by a single process (consumer process).

I would also limit the number of processes that you create to the number of processors on your computer. Creating too many processes introduces a lot of overhead.

If you really feel like you need the 200 threads you suggested in your post, I would program this in Java or C++.

Comment: What I would need is probably not 200 threads at once, but 4 threads. When the slowest instrument returns its value, I would then read those values, and spawn 4 new threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fits your requirements I'm not too familiar with pyVisa, however have you looked into pypy's stackless examples the speed increase is pretty impressive, and you're able to spawn almost infinite amount of 'threadlets' without much hindrance to your system / program.

pypy is kinda limited in terms of supporting various packages but looks like pyVisa isn't one of them.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVISA